# Absolute value module in Verilog returning only unknown values

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement a simple 16-bit absolute value module; however, I am only getting unknown values as output.

Below is the code that I've written:

```
module refabs(b, a);
input wire [15:0] a;
output reg signed [15:0] b;
    always @* begin
        b = ((a < 0) ? -a : a);
    end
endmodule

module testbench;
reg [15:0] a;
wire [15:0] b;
refabs abs(b, a);
initial begin
a = -30000;
    begin
    $display("refabs(%x) = %x", a, b);
    end
end
endmodule
```

The output I get is:

```
refabs(8ad0) = xxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `initial` block executes with 0 delay without giving the `always @*` a chance to execute.

Either change your `$display` to `$strobe`, or add a delay before the `$display` statement.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the ouput issue. However, it still doesn't correctly convert the numbers to their positive counterparts. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Your `input wire [15:0] a;` is unsigned. So `a<0` can never be true.